# extend logback and allow clients to use clean slf4j

Tags: java, logging, architecture, slf4j, logback

I am building a logger for several projects using slf4j and logback, and on top of the functionality that comes with the logger I want to add a few more methods to the Logger: log.debug(String key, String[] params, Throwable throwable) (and same for info, warn and error). The key will take a string from a resource file and will fill it with params from String[] and log it.
I want the users to use clean slf4j and not be bound to logback if that is possible. 
I was thinking about extending logback with my functionality and writing a binding for slf4j to my extended new logback. 
Is that the right way to go? if so how do I extend logback?
and by looking at other bindings I understand they are not implementing markers. Is there an example of binding to something that does? so i could use that as skeleton for the "logback extended" binding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ended up extending the org.slf4j.Logger with a new interface, then implemented that interface.
Projects using my logger won't need to change their code in case ill switch from logback.
The implementation of course simply route to the slf4j implementation except for the added methods.

Answer (score 1):

I agree that SLF4J lacks that all-args-in-one method for reporting exceptions, but I don't see the need for it in other types (info, warn...).

You could create a utility class `LoggerWrapper` that would have those methods:

```
class LoggerWrapper extends Logger {
    private Logger logger;
    private ResourceBundle bundle;

    public LoggerWrapper(Logger logger, ResourceBundle bundle) {
        this.logger = logger;
        this.bundle = bundle;
    }

    public void error(final String key, Object[] params, Throwable cause) {
        logger.error(String.format(bundle.getString(key), params), cause);
    }
    ...
}
```

Example usage:

```
class Something {
    private static LoggerWrapper logger = new LoggerWrapper(
            Logger.getLog(Something.class),
            ResourceBundle.getBundle("ErrorMessages"));

    ...
    private void doSomething(Object params...) {
        try {
            // Do something that could fail.
        }
        catch (SomeException e) {
            logger.error("error.something.failed", params, e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That actually sound like a good idea, the only problem is that I can't extend Logger (its a final class). :\